# Django annotate over a subquery

Tags: python, django

i'm struggling with an aggregation, what I'm trying to do is, to perform some sum over a subquery.
Let's assume the following model:

```
+------------------------+-----------+
| Column                 |    Type   |
+------------------------+-----------+
| customer               |     fk    |
+------------------------+-----------+
| total                  |   float   |
+------------------------+-----------+
| somefield              | charfield |
+------------------------+-----------+
| issued_on              |    date   |
+------------------------+-----------+
| validation_status_code | charfield |
+------------------------+-----------+
```

the subquery is as follow:

```
Invoice.objects.filter(customer_id=4).order_by('issued_on')[:48+1]
```

This is only half of the invoices of a customer, the idea here is to obtain the aggregate over a period of time (this is the subquery).

Suppose I want to get the Sum of total, the Sum of the total if the status is "error" and gruop by 'somefield',

I've figured it out the SQL query (it's on mysql), I want to know if it's possible to do this via Django ORM.

The query is the following:

```
SELECT 
table1.somefield,
SUM(table1.total) AS total_clean,
SUM(CASE
    WHEN table1.validation_status_code = 'error' THEN table1.total
    ELSE NULL
END) AS canceladas,
(SUM(table1.total) - SUM(CASE
    WHEN table1.validation_status_code = 'error' THEN table1.total
    ELSE NULL
END)) AS ventas
FROM
(SELECT 
        invoice.id,
        invoice.customer_id,
        invoice.total,
        invoice.somefield,
        invoice.validation_status_code,
        invoice.issued_on,
FROM
    invoice
WHERE
    invoice.customer_id = 4
ORDER BY invoice.issued_on ASC
LIMIT 49) AS table1
GROUP BY table1.somefield
```

Comment: If you would share the other model as well it might be quite easier to help you with the query; in general it should be possible with something similar to `your_queryset.annotate(total_clean=Sum('total'), canceladas=Sum(Case(When(validation_status_code='error', then='total'), default=0))).annotate(ventas=F('total_clean') - F('canceladas'))`

Comment: Thanks, the model is at the beginning of the description or do you mean the customer model?